# Null values when using pivot function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Using tsql I have a number of summed columns I need to pivot out across various groupings and payment statuses.

Before:

```
+---------------+----------+----------------------------+
| policy number | Grouping |          £ Amount          |
+---------------+----------+----------------------------+
| #123          | a        | £1 (for issued payment)    |
| #123          | b        | £11(for cancelled payment) |
| #123          | a        | £21(for cancelled payment) |
| #123          | b        | £31(for issued payment)    |
+---------------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Desired after:

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| policy | Group a Issued | Group b Issued | Group a cancelled | Group b cancelled |
+--------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| #123   | £1             | £31            | £21               | £11               |
+--------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Despite using isnull function when producing the summed columns in the before table, all my results are null. I have checked my pre-pivot table exhaustively and there are no null values.

Note because I have to pivot out the groupings across multiple payments types, I have had to use duplicated group columns.

Comment: if you post your tsql, we can determine where your mistakes might be.

Comment: Please post your query, otherwise no one can help you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i have since resolved this issue